# How can I get the issuer of a css request in `css-loader` getLocalIdent?

Tags: webpack, css-loader

I want to use the `getLocalIdent` function for changing the `css-module` classes output name. Actually I want to access the issuer file name of a CSS file. for example, if I import my CSS file in `a.js` file, I want to get the `a.js` filename (or path) in the `getLocalIdent`.

In the development mode, I can access it with `context._module.issuer.issuer.resource` but in the production, `_module.issuer` is null.

How can I access to the issuer string?

```
getLocalIdent: (context, _localIdentName, localName, _options) => {
    return generateScopedName(localName, context._module.issuer.issuer.resource);
},
```